# How to make only AlertDialog's button clickable when dialog is showing

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog

i have an AlertDialog on my Android app. When i show to AlertDialog i want to disable only when users click "OKAY" button. Because i reset the screen when users clicked "OKAY" button.

My problem is when i click somewhere on screen outside of AlertDialog, dialog is closing but i can not clean the screen.

This is my code;

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameOnePlayer.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
//builder.setCancelable(true);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(GameOnePlayer.this).inflate(
        R.layout.layout_winner_dialog,
        (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutAlertDialogContainer)
);
builder.setView(view);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
//alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlertDialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hideSystemUI();
        clearScreen();
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
});

if(alertDialog.getWindow() != null){
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
}

alertDialog.show();
```

I tried alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); but it did'not work.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

This is my style.xml

What do I have to do for this? Thanks.

Edit: I tried these advices but did not work.

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Edit2:
Hi i found the solution on the other post.
Just added these line in the onCreate method.

`this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);`

Many thanks for all you helpers.

Comment: Why not adding `builder.setCancelable(false);`?

Comment: Also it can be related to `onCancel` and `onDismiss` methods. You can write them.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Thank you i will try these and will back here when i finish.

Comment: Hi Shalu T D, i solve the problem. Many thanks for your advice. The solution is define this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); in onCreate method.

Comment: Never heard about this method. It is strange, maybe something wrong.

Comment: Hi CoolMind why you think something is wrong?

Comment: Because it usually is not needed. `setCancelable...(false);` methods are sufficient. If something more needed, maybe there are specific settings (styles, call parameters, etc.). I don't know, probably you are right, as there are so many programmers who were affected by this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
  alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
  alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for quick answer. It did'not work i can click outside screen of dialog still.

Comment: @ccanozerr  did you try with `builder.setCancelable(false);` ?

Comment: Yes, he tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.setCancelable(false)
```

Put this line below the "builder.setView(view)" line so your dialog is not close when you touch outside the dialog or when you press back button your dialog is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add OnCancelListener to your dialog to listen Dialog cancellation and perform the screen reset.

```
      builder.setOnCancelListener { 
                 //call your method to reset the screen
               }
```